# I can't use push_to_git_remote() in fastlane

Tags: ios, xcode, gitlab, gitlab-ci, fastlane

I have an issue with gitlab, gitlab-ci and fastlane. In fastlane, I am using :

```
  def increment_build_and_commit
    incrementBuildNumber()
    commit_version_bump(message: 'build number bump [skip ci]')
    push_to_git_remote(
    remote: 'origin_rw',
    remote_branch: ENV['CI_COMMIT_BRANCH']
    )   
  end
```

So I want to increase build number and commit. So it does the job with:

```
incrementBuildNumber(),
commit_version_bump(message: 'build number bump [skip ci]')
```

But when running, it fails at push_to_git_remote

> [!] Exit status of command 'git push origin_rw HEAD:HEAD --tags
> --set-upstream' was 1 instead of 0.  error: The destination you provided is not a full refname (i.e.,  starting with "refs/"). We
> tried to guess what you meant by:
>
> - Looking for a ref that matches 'HEAD' on the remote side.
> - Checking if the  being pushed ('HEAD')    is a ref in "refs/{heads,tags}/". If so we add a corresponding
>   refs/{heads,tags}/ prefix on the remote side.  Neither worked, so we
>   gave up. You must fully qualify the ref.  hint: The  part of the
>   refspec is a commit object.  hint: Did you mean to create a new branch
>   by pushing to  hint: 'HEAD:refs/heads/HEAD'?  error: failed to push
>   some refs to '**********.git'

Some of you have any clues what to do and how to solve this problem? As I am going to be a google machine on that, but unfortunetly can't find the solution.
**Thanks in advance!!**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because gitlab-ci checkouts git commit instead of git branch and you enter detached HEAD state.

There are few ways to get around this:

1) **Use CI provided value.** For GitLab I would recommend using `CI_PIPELINE_IID`. Downside is that you cannot control it and if you migrate your project to other repository it will start from 1 again.

2) **Checkout git branch before making commit.** Downside is that if other developer pushes to the same branch, your pipeline will continue with wrong source code.

3) **Commit version number bump manually.**